# Чем отличаются снимки от различий?

Tags: git, контроль-версий

[В документации к Git'у](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git) во втором абзаце написано, что подход Git’а к хранению данных больше похож на набор снимков миниатюрной файловой системы.

А определённый снимок это по сути не есть различие в файлах? В чём конкретное отличие?

Comment: отличия могут быть между **одним** снимком и **другим** снимком. сам от себя снимок ничем не отличается. ну и вообще вопрос стоит закрыть как чистую казуистику.

Comment: Наверное не полностью описал то, что мне непонятно.
Мне непонятно различие между Git и другими СКВ в подходе для работы с данными.
Один работает со снимками, а другие с различиями в файлах.
Чем снимки отличаются от этих самых различий?

Comment: программа *git* хранит снимки. снимки, а не отличия между снимками. не отличия между снимаками, а сами снимки. а отличия **потом** при запросе может вычислить и показать вам. но сами отличия не хранит. зачем ей отличия? вот одна скв хранила отилчия, дали ей в лоб, теперь не хранит.

Comment: Т.е. если я добавлю в файл(закомиченный ранее) один символ и сделаю коммит, git сохранит весь этот файл целиком в своём хранилище?

Comment: да, сохранит целиком.

Comment: понял, спасибо.

Comment: @Undefined Почитайте [10. Git изнутри](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/Git-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%A4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80). Там об этом подробнее.